# How to pass arguments dynamically to the anova test?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, feature-extraction, anova

I have a df, from this df i want to pass arguments for Anova test. but the problem is here df values are dynamic. How to pass arguments into `scipy.stats.f_oneway` this.

For Example:

```
    num    cat
0   164  type1
1   172  type1
2   168  type1
3   177  type1
4   156  type1
5   195  type1
6   178  type2
7   191  type2
8   197  type2
9   182  type2
10  185  type2
11  177  type2
12  175  type3
13  193  type3
14  178  type3
15  171  type3
16  163  type3
17  176  type3
18  155  type4
19  166  type4
20  149  type4
21  164  type4
22  170  type4
23  168  type4
```

I have to pass the values like below,

```
t1 = [164, 172, 168, 177, 156, 195]
t2 = [178, 191, 197, 182, 185, 177]
t3 = [175, 193, 178, 171, 163, 176]
t4 = [155, 166, 149, 164, 170, 168]

F, p = stats.f_oneway(t1,t2,t3,t4)
```

In the above approach i have to store the values of each type into separate variable. But I want to avoid this. because my values are dynamic. For example, the above sample df has only 4 types,here this 4 is dynamic, it can be anything at running time.

So far I can get the values into list using below.

```
result = df.groupby(1)[0].apply(list).values.tolist()
```

But I don't know how to pass this value into `scipy.stats.f_oneway`.

Please give a good approach to solve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `*` for [unpacking lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
result = df.groupby('cat')['num'].apply(list)
print (result)
cat
type1    [164, 172, 168, 177, 156, 195]
type2    [178, 191, 197, 182, 185, 177]
type3    [175, 193, 178, 171, 163, 176]
type4    [155, 166, 149, 164, 170, 168]
Name: num, dtype: object

F, p = scipy.stats.f_oneway(*result)
print (F)
5.406342913776015
print (p)
0.0068759477547351
```